# ClassCastException vs. "inconvertible types" compilation error

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors, classcastexception

So I wanted to know on what situations Java throws `ClassCastException` and when it's "inconvertible types" compilation error. I guess it's something about interfaces.

I mean with interfaces there is more difficult situation. For example:

```
interface SomeInterface {}
class SomeClass {}
SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();
SomeInterface someInterface  = (SomeInterface)someObject;
```

throws `ClassCastException` thought It's clear at compile time, that `SomeClass` object cannot be casted to `SomeInterface`.

Comment: Review the IS-A test...

Comment: It doesn't *have* to involve interfaces, but using interfaces is a common place to encounter it.

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary about interfaces. A cast tells the compiler that you're going to reference an instance of one type, from a variable of another type.

When the type conversión suggested by the cast is impossible, you get a compilation error.

i.e. `String s = (String) new Integer(1);`

When sometimes it's possible and sometimes not, the code compiles, but you may get a ClassCastException.

i.e.

```
Object o = ...;
String s = (String) o;//Depending on the content of o, this line may throw a ClassCastException
```

Comment: More importantly, while you can "sneak" something past the compiler, you cannot avoid the runtime ClassCastException if the cast is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

- If you use a **interfaces**, then generally you have a *runtime exception.*
- If you use a **class**, then generally you have a *compile time
  error.*

ex.:

```
interface Fruct{}
class Banana{}
Fruct fruct = (Fruct) new Banana();       // Compile OK, but throw a ClassCastException
```

vs.

```
class Fruct{}           
class Banana{}
Fruct fruct = (Fruct) new Banana();          // Compile-Time-Error: Inconvertible types
```

Answer (score 0):

Inconvertible types compiler error occur for `A a = (A) b` when `b` is not a reference for any super or subclasses of `A`.
for example:

```
Integer iii = new Integer(0);
String sss = (String) iii;
```

Here `iii` is not a reference for any super or subclasses of `String`. In other words, since String and Integers are unrelated, such cast can't be done.

`ClassCastException` occur when `for A a = (A) b` when `b`'s reference type is of a superclass of A but not referencing an instance of A.
for example:

```
Object ooo = new Integer(0);
String sss = (String) ooo;
```

Here `ooo` is not referencing an instance of `String` but its reference type is a superclass of `A`